# Shell script to change password policy by replacing text in PAM files

Tags: shell, scripting, newline

I'm working on a shell script that will completely change the password policy using the PAM files in Ubuntu 14.04. The way I'm doing this is

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "I want to change this text" >/etc/pam.d/example.txt'
```

The problem I'm running into is that I can't create a new line. I've researched this, and some people say that the HTML tag `<br>` works, but I've tried

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "I want to change this text. <br> This should be a new line." >/etc/pam.d/example.txt
```

(and)

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "I want to change this text. <br /> This should be a new line." >/etc/pam.d/example.txt'
```

but it just prints the `<br>` and `<br />` tags on the text file. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you should stop using `echo` for anything new you're writing.

While POSIX describes the behaviour of `echo`, in practice it's not as portable as it could be. POSIX documentation for [echo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_16) even recommends that "*New applications are encouraged to use [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94_18) instead of echo.*"

You can also find references to this [here on the S.E. network](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo). And [the bash hackers' wiki touches on this too](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf). And it's mentioned in [one of the bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf14).

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "First line.\nSecond line.\n" >/etc/pam.d/example.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-e` flag in `echo` to enable back-slashed escape sequences (on `echo` which comes as part of `GNU coreutils`) ,

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -e "I want to change this text\nThis should be a new line" '
I want to change this text
This should be a new line
```

For your case, it should be,

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -e "I want to change this text\nThis should be a new line" > /etc/pam.d/example.txt'
```

On [`POSIX echo`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/echo/) statements you can directly embed the `\n` characters without the `-e` flag,

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "I want to change this text\nThis should be a new line" > /etc/pam.d/example.txt'
```

Comment: Heya. Note that the behaviour of `echo` differs between implementations of /bin/sh. For example, bash (the default /bin/sh on some systems) behaves differently from dash (the default /bin/sh on my old ubuntu box), and in OS X the builtin echo in the bash that is /bin/sh is different from the one in /bin/bash and also different from /bin/echo. Safer just not to use echo at all if portability might be important.